# How do I use multiple environments with copycopter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

(Using Rails 3.2.1) When using the copycopter-server app and editing the copy, it suggests that you can save as a draft and it will only submit to the development/staging sites or, if you click publish, it will save it to all environments- including production.

My question is- how do I setup these environments with copycopter? I've looked all over the place. The Railcast mentions the fact that you can use the feature, but never explains what you need to do in order to set it up.

Does anyone have any experience or with this?

Answer (score 1):

I found in a (google) cached version of help.copycopter.com that you need to specify the environment in the copycopter.rb config file.

Change copycopter.rb to this:

```
CopycopterClient.configure do |config|
  config.api_key = 'your_api_key_here'
  config.host = 'host.name'
  config.environment_name = Rails.env
end
```

Now, when you save something as a draft, it will populate to your development/staging servers automatically. When you publish something, it will populate all servers (including production). I'm not sure why they didn't add this to the original documentation, it took a long time to find.